# Error 91 in VBA when variables are already defined and set

Tags: excel, vba, internet-explorer, automation, runtime-error

I'm a newbie at coding and this is my first post on StackOverflow.
I'm trying to automate a repetitive task at my work.

So it's a matter to login, then deleting a text field (where the "0000" should be, just for example), then pasting another value from Excel in another field, clicking on search and scrape some data.

```
 HTMLInput.Value = "0000000"
```

Here above is where I get the

> Runtime error 91: Object variable or With not set

and I really don't get why is this happening. I thought that every variable is defined.

Or am I missing something after the login, like something else should happen to 'HTMLInput'?

```
Option Explicit

Sub LogIn()

    Dim IE As New SHDocVw.InternetExplorer
    Dim HTMLDoc As MSHTML.HTMLDocument
    Dim HTMLInput As MSHTML.IHTMLElement

    IE.Visible = True

    IE.Navigate Sheet1.Range("B2").Text

    Do While IE.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
    DoEvents
    Loop

    Set HTMLDoc = IE.Document

    'Setting Username to a specific value
    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_WebPartManager1_gwpLogin1_Login1_UserName")
    HTMLInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("B3")

    'Setting Password to a specific value
    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_WebPartManager1_gwpLogin1_Login1_Password")
    HTMLInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("B4")

    'Click to login
    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_WebPartManager1_gwpLogin1_Login1_LoginButton")

    HTMLInput.Click

    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_txtEMail")

    HTMLInput.Value = "0000000"

    Set HTMLInput = HTMLDoc.getElementById("ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_txtCustomerID")
    HTMLInput.Value = Sheet1.Range("A10")

End Sub
```

Comment: It would appear that your `Set HTMLInput = ...` statement returns `NULL` before you attempt to set the `Value` to `0000000`.  You can't set the value of _nothing_

Comment: Try to check in your web page whether input element has the exact id as 'ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_txtEMail'. Check for its spelling. If it is incorrect then try to correct it.

Comment: Hi Martin, the reason i have to set the value of that text field to empty is because all text fields have to be empty before searching for a specific item("A10"). That text field that has to be empy contains already some text everytime i log in.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT The HTML id (ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_txtEMail) contains only one specific text field

Comment: Maybe another thing to mention is that after the code clicks on Log in, the page redirects to the platform i need. So i'm guessing if i'm missing some code lines after the login and the beginning of the next steps. Or should i make a new Sub?

Comment: I think your IE.document object gets changed after the login. So it is referring to the redirected page. After that, it is searching for 'ctl00_SearchSection_ObjectSearch_txtEMail' on that page and as it is not available on that page your code is generating an error. To solve the issue you need to reassign the old page to the IE.document object.

Comment: @Deepak-MSFT Hi, Thank you for your reply. I think indeed that i have to reassign something after the Login due the redirection of the page( I guess the code will search too fast for the HTML elements while the page isn't loaded yet). I have unfortunately no clue how to optimize the structure of something like that, can you maybe share some of your knowledge? And shall i make another subroutine to make a difference between the login and the next steps(to keep the overview?)
Thank you in advance

Comment: I suggest you to put the break point and try to debug the code step by step and check the result in IE browser after each step execution. It will help you to understand the issue properly. If web page get changed after the login then again try to navigate to the old page and then try to search for other elements. Check whether it works or not. If you see any other issue then let us know about it. we will try to provide further suggestions.